# Qt Console Application missing in New Project wizard in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

For some reason the Qt Console Application entry is missing from the New Project wizard in my Qt Creator 3.3.0.

### How it looks on my computer:

[image]

### How it should look normally:

[image]

Any idea why it's missing and how to bring it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that it was because I had selected Android Templates in the combo at the top-right. I hadn't noticed that Combo at all and I have no idea how it got that way.

[image]

Changing it to All Templates fixed the problem.